# How To Change Telnet username and password using SNMP

Tags: snmp, telnet, dsl, net-snmp

We have a Siemens h1000 dslam.
We forgot the username and password but i think we can do all activity with snmp
My question is How we can reset telnet username and password using SNMP?

Edited->

I can access to the dslam using snmp and can read and write settings via snmp.

for example i can change the sysLocation(oid=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6)

Answer (score 1):

You must have the following items:

1. SNMP read/write comunity for SNMP v1, and v2c or username/password that has read/write access for SNMP v3.
2. The `mib` file from the manufacturer to find out the `OID` that you will need to use to have access to user table. If the equipment is not supporting password reset via SNMP, this can be found from these MIBs. Password reset via SNMP capability is dependent on the manufacturer.
3. SNMP client

If you do not have any of those components, the only solution is to reset the configuration of the equipment. Most manufacturers allows this with a combination of a button(s) (like reset one). Most equipments have an on board TTL3V serial, I2C and/or JTAG port. You can use those too.

Comment: You've left one rather important item off the list. The device must be capable of having the password reset via SNMP. Simply having write access doesn't mean a given item can be changed.

Comment: @Mircea I can access to the dslam using snmp and can write and read settings via snmp.
for example i can change the sysLocation(oid=1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6)

Comment: @Ali Do you have the mib from the manufacturer for this equipment?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers you are right. I thought that password reset capability can be found out by reading the MIBs of the equipment.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici i have the mib files but the mib file is too huge and i didn't find any telnet string in the mibs! as you know there is no good document on snmp using. 
i can upload mibs if you want;)

Comment: @Ali You might need to search for a user table where you should have a password field. Can you please add the URL where the MIB is located to the question?

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici the mib files are located in http://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~modaresi/test/mibs.zip

Comment: The only password I've found in those MIBs is 1.3.6.1.4.1.231.2.31.2.9 omnisSettingsAPASS from Omnis-Management-MIB.mib file. You can also read this variable.